# UIImagePickerController through model popup in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Hello friends I want to open imagepicker view after clicking on the image button of my popup view. Now the point is it works fine perfectly without popup. But I dont know how to implement it within modem popup. How can I ?

Comment: Please post code and be clear what you want. Currently your question contains confusing information which is hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

// try this,.

```
     if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
      imagePickerController_.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
              [popover_ presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:sender
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        ...


       }
```

here sender is the object where you click // UIButton

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you

```
 -(IBAction)Click_event
   {
     UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController_=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     UIPopoverController *popover_=[[UIPopoverController alloc]
   initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController_];

     if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

        imagePickerController_.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [popover_ presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400, 400, 0, 0) inView:self.Mybutton
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
   }
```